# Prevent additional connections to hub in SignalR JS client with Angular

Tags: angularjs, signals

I have an angular resource that looks like this

```
angular.module('hubProxy', ['ngResource'])
   .factory('eventStream', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
       'use strict';


       return {

           on: function (eventName, callback) {
               var connection = $.hubConnection();
               var hubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('mainHub');

               hubProxy.on(eventName, function () {
                   var args = arguments;
                   $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                       callback.apply(hubProxy, args);
                   });
               });

               connection.start(function() { console.log('connection started!'); });

           }
       };
   }]);
```

I need to call this resource multiple times, but I don't want to keep making new connections

So I either need to disconnect each time, or recycle the existing connection

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need recycle the existing connection.

Try this

```
angular.module('hubProxy', ['ngResource'])
.factory('eventStream', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
   'use strict';

   var connection = $.hubConnection();
   var hubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('mainHub');
   connection.start(function() { console.log('connection started!'); }); 
   return {
       on: function (eventName, callback) {               
           hubProxy.on(eventName, function () {
               var args = arguments;
               $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                   callback.apply(hubProxy, args);
               });
           });
       }
   };
  }]);
```